# Is there a way to filter tweets?

Tags: twitter

There is a certain young singer who I do not like but who is very popular on Twitter. Is there some way I can block tweets (aka make them invisible) so I don't have to look at his name anymore, and all the spam related to him? A Safari extension is also fine.

---

<sub>If this isn't already there I have to actually implement it myself. :(</sub>

Answer (score 4):

There is an extension called [Tweetfilter](http://tweetfilter.netne.net/) for Safari 5+

[image: Options Available]

The above image is from Google Chrome using Twitter's web client.
As an example I will try with the current trending Charlie Sheen.

So I match the following in the filter

- Charlie
- Sheen
- CharlieSheen
- @charliesheen

And the results that do not appear in my timeline.

Notice this will not work on your own tweets/searches/lists. I have not tried to check to see what happens if someone mentions you within a filtered tweet.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/41201) is a script for Greasemonkey/Greasekit which ignores tweets with specified hashtags.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: It does not work with the new Twitter.

Answer (score -1):

[Refynr](http://Refynr.com) is a web client focused on filtering in (or out) by keywords, users, or hashtags on Twitter & Facebook.

So, you just add #tigerblood, Sheen, & #winning to your Filter List and you'll have a clean Refynr Stream.

[full disclosure: I'm the founder and creator]. I hope you find it useful, and let me know if you want a Beta Invite code.